# Stay open context menu after click

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I've got datagrid with context menu. It is initialized programatically:

```
contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

foreach (var col in this.Columns)
{
    var checkBox = new MenuItem()
    {
        Header = col.Header
    };
    Binding myBinding = new Binding("Visibility");
    myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    myBinding.Converter = new IsCheckedToVisibilityConverter();
    checkBox.DataContext = col;
    checkBox.SetBinding(MenuItem.IsCheckedProperty, myBinding);
    checkBox.Click += checkBox_Click;
    checkBox.Checked += checkBox_Checked;
    checkBox.Unchecked += checkBox_Unchecked;
    contextMenu.Items.Add(checkBox);

}
```

It works great, but i would like to stay open context menu after check\uncheck menuitems. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After adding `checkBox.StaysOpenOnClick = true;` works as expected

```
contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

            foreach (var col in this.Columns)
            {
                var checkBox = new MenuItem()
                {
                    Header = col.Header
                };
                //binding
                Binding myBinding = new Binding("Visibility");
                myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
                myBinding.Converter = new IsCheckedToVisibilityConverter();
                checkBox.DataContext = col;
                checkBox.SetBinding(MenuItem.IsCheckedProperty, myBinding);
                checkBox.Click += checkBox_Click;
                checkBox.Checked += checkBox_Checked;
                checkBox.Unchecked += checkBox_Unchecked;
                checkBox.StaysOpenOnClick = true;
                contextMenu.Items.Add(checkBox);

            }
```

Comment: StaysOpenOnClick did the trick. You can use this only on certain menu items which should stay open on check/uncheck.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
private bool close= true; 

private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 close= false; 
}

private void contextMenu_Closing(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosingEventArgs e)
{
  e.Cancel = !close;
  CloseContextMenu = true;
}
```

Comment: Im sorry, but How can i catch contextmenu closing event ??

Comment: Damn I forget the contextmenu has no closing event. Well then maybe Collapse event will work, but I'm not sure.
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?551802-RESOLVED-2008-ContextMenu-Closed-Event